# make sql query with Inner Join

Tags: sql

I've got these tables in my database:

**Tourist** - this is the first table

1. Tourist_ID - primary key
2. name...etc...

**EXTRA_CHARGES**

1. Extra_Charge_ID - primary key
2. Excursion_ID - foreign key
3. Extra_Charge_Description

**Tourist_Extra_Charges**

1. Tourist_Extra_charge_ID
2. Extra_Charge_ID - foreign key
3. Tourist_ID - foreign key

**Reservations**

1. Reservation_ID - primary key
2. .....

**Tourist_Reservations**

1. Tourist_Reservation_ID
2. Reservation_ID - foreign key
3. Tourist_ID - foreign key

---

So here is my example: I've got reservation with `Reservaton_ID = 27`
This reservation has two tourists with `Tourist_ID = 86` and `Tourist_ID = 87`
This Tourist with id 86 has extra charges with `Extra_Charge_ID = 7` and  `Extra_charge_ID = 11`;

The problem is here that tourist belong to Excursion with `Excursion_ID = 6`;
So this excursion has also extra-charges with `Extra_Charge_ID = 8` and `Extra_Charge_ID = 9`; (Except from those with ID 7 and 11)

Is it possible to make SQL query  to get this `Extra_Charge_ID` which doesn't belong to these `Tourists_ID` but belong to their `Excursion_ID` (I mean to get Extra_charge_Id: 8 and 9)

(Here is the query I made to get the extra_charge_description of all of the tourists with `Reservation_ID = 27` but I don't know how to change it.)

```
 string selectTouristExtraCharges =
        "Select EXTRA_CHARGES.Extra_Charge_Description,TOURIST_EXTRA_CHARGES.Tourist_ID FROM EXTRA_CHARGES";
         selectTouristExtraCharges+=" INNER JOIN TOURIST_EXTRA_CHARGES on EXTRA_CHARGES.Extra_Charge_ID = TOURIST_EXTRA_CHARGES.Extra_Charge_ID";
         selectTouristExtraCharges+=" INNER JOIN TOURIST_RESERVATION on TOURIST_EXTRA_CHARGES.Tourist_ID = TOURIST_RESERVATION.Tourist_ID";
         selectTouristExtraCharges+=" INNER JOIN  RESERVATIONS on RESERVATIONS.Reservation_ID = TOURIST_RESERVATION.Reservation_ID";
         selectTouristExtraCharges += " where RESERVATIONS.Reservation_ID=27";
```

Comment: It's possible if you can link Tourist table to Excursion table and Excursion table to ExtraCharges table.

Comment: and how would look like the query

Answer (score 0):

As a developer you need to do these :

1) Start drawing a diagram of data-structure; Like this:
[image]
That I add `tourist_excursion` table in it.

2) Rewrite you current query and understand it - [+ optimization]-:

```
Select ec.Extra_Charge_Description, tec.Tourist_ID 
From EXTRA_CHARGES As ec INNER JOIN 
    TOURIST_EXTRA_CHARGES as tec on ec.Extra_Charge_ID = tec.Extra_Charge_ID INNER JOIN 
    TOURIST_RESERVATION as tr on tec.Tourist_ID = tr.Tourist_ID 
where tr.Reservation_ID=27
```

That in this query an `inner join` removed and understanding getting better.

3) Try to find other clues :

```
Select ec.Extra_Charge_Description, tec.Tourist_ID 
From EXTRA_CHARGES As ec INNER JOIN
    TOURIST_EXCURSION as te on ec.Excursion_ID = te.Exursion_ID INNER JOIN 
    TOURIST_RESERVATION as tr on te.Tourist_ID = tr.Tourist_ID 
where tr.Reservation_ID=27
```

That in this query you can found the second clue of your question -List of Extra_Charges of reservation by Excursion-

4) find your solution:

**Solution**

1. At first find results of the query of second clue.
2. If it has any results return result; else continue.
3. Find results of the first -and old- query and return them.